# Generating Random Sample to Fit LM Output

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, random-generation

I am trying to reverse generate a dataset that led to a certain R lm() output, l

[image]

I tried to generate random sample like this, and ran lm()

```
N = 1000
u = rnorm(N,sd=100)
v = rnorm(N,sd=100)
w = rnorm(N,sd=100)
x = rnorm(N,sd=100)
y = 1.42 + 1.0359*u + 0.92*v + + 0.72*w + rnorm(N,sd=30)
j = lm(y ~ u + v + w )
print(summary(j))
```

The output

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ u + v + w)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-91.694 -18.978  -1.255  19.476  88.170 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.792752   0.934062   1.919   0.0552 .  
u           1.040783   0.009449 110.145   <2e-16 ***
v           0.916439   0.009593  95.529   <2e-16 ***
w           0.703660   0.009478  74.241   <2e-16 ***
---
Residual standard error: 29.51 on 996 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9638,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9637 
F-statistic:  8832 on 3 and 996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

It sort of comes close but R^2 is off, and standard errors and t value are off as well.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Since you generate the covariates as well, there is no reason you should recover the same output. For instance, the original lm() output gives you some information about the $X^\text{T}X$ matrix through the `Std. Error`.

Comment: Do you know the correlations between `u`, `v`, `w`, and `y` in the original dataset?

Comment: No I dont; all I know is what I see on the lm output.